# $(this) persisting into .get call success

Tags: jquery, this

I'm trying to reference `$(this)` but jquery can't find it. Simple code:

```
$(".testBox").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("backRed");
    $.get("/data/TESTer/?tickle=yes", function(data) {
        $(this).addClass("backGreen");
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

In this scenario, the `.testBox` will get the class `backRed`, but will not get the class `backGreen`, probably because `$(this)` is now referencing something from the `$.get`.  How can I reference the clicked `$(this)` within the `$.get` parameters?

Comment: This is why [coffeescript's](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) fat arrow (`=>`) is so handy. They also give a good description of what is happening.

Comment: ^^^ Ten unicorns just died, coffeescript is never handy, it's just added layers of strangeness to make javascript look weirder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to create a closure like this:

```
$(".testBox").click(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    me.addClass("backRed");
    $.get("/data/TESTer/?tickle=yes", function(data) {
        me.addClass("backGreen");
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

What this does is:

- create a local scope variable that stores the `$(this)`.
- use that variable in the inner-function

What happens is that it will create a *closure*, a function that has a reference to an outer parent and can use variables from that parent.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(".testBox").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass("backRed");
        $.get("/data/TESTer/?tickle=yes", function(data) {
            $this.addClass("backGreen");
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is probably to do this:

```
$(".testBox").click(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.addClass("backRed");
    $.get("/data/TESTer/?tickle=yes", function(data) {
        self.addClass("backGreen");
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool, but accept @Andrei's answer as he's gone to more effort to explain _why_ it works that way.

Answer (score 1):

Cache the selector into `$this`

```
$(".testBox").click(function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("backRed");
    $.get("/data/TESTer/?tickle=yes", function(data) {
        $this.addClass("backGreen");
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$.ajax()` method (from which `$.get()` is derived) has a `context` argument that is specifically meant to control the value of `this` in the success handler.

So, you could use that option:

```
$(".testBox").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("backRed");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/data/TESTer/?tickle=yes",
        context: this, 
        success: function(data) {
            $(this).addClass("backGreen");
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        }
    });
});
```